# Reading data from file

Tags: python, file

This reads a list of points from a file with a certain format:

> ```
> <number of points>
> x1 y1
> x2 y2
> ```

How I can make it better?

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point ', ['x', 'y'])
def read():
    ins = open("PATH_TO_FILE", "r")
    array = []
    first = True
    expected_length = 0
    for line in ins:
        if first:
            expected_length = int(line.rstrip('\n'))
            first = False
        else:
            parsed = line.rstrip('\n').split ()
            array.append(Point(int(parsed[0]), int(parsed[1])))
    if expected_length != len(array):
        raise NameError("error on read")
    return  array
```

Comment: If you're dealing with points you might want to use a library like Shapely, which will give you a nice Point object.

Comment: @monkut, thx I'll see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another improvement is to use `open` as a context manager so that you don't have to remember to `.close()` the file object even if there are errors while reading.

```
def read():
    with open("FILE", "r") as f:
        array = []
        expected_length = int(f.next())
        for line in f:
            parsed = map(int, line.split())
            array.append(Point(*parsed))
        if expected_length != len(array):
            raise NameError('error on read')
        return array
```

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.close for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need all that `expected_length` and `first=True` stuff.  You can treat a file as an iterator, and it will return objects until it quits, so you can just use the `.next()` method and throw item away, or save it to a variable if you wish.  In that sense, it's best to write two functions-- one to deal with the file, and another to deal with a single line as provided by the file object.

```
def lineparse(line):
    ''' Parses a single line. '''
    # your code goes here

def fileparse(filepath):
    f = open(filepath, "r")
    n = int(f.next()) # this also advances your iterator by one line
    while True: 
        yield lineparse(f.next())
    f.close()

data = list(fileparse(filepath))
```

Comment: `expected_length` is a check that the supposed length of the array equals the amount of data, you can't just ignore it.

Comment: Ah ignore me, I've just noticed you use `n =` to get the expected length. Still a bit confusing that you say you don't need `expected_length` though.

Answer (score 3):

Not that big a change but you don't need to worry about stripping out `\n`s as the `split` and `int` functions will take care of that. Secondly, as already pointed out, you can grab the first line by just calling `.next()` then use a loop for the remaining lines.

```
def read():
    ins = open("FILE", "r")
    array = []
    expected_length = int(ins.next())
    for line in ins:
        parsed = line.split()
        array.append(Point(int(parsed[0]), int(parsed[1])))
    if expected_length != len(array):
        raise NameError('error on read')
    ins.close()
    return array
```